# How to Access Yahoo Finance YQL query with historical data

Tags: jsonp, yql, stocks, yahoo-finance

I'm new to YQL. Perhaps this is very trivial, but I couldn't quite figure this out. I know, for instance, how to query current stock data from Yahoo/YQL using the YQL console:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/

with the query string:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")
```

However, what if I want, say, the same data from yesterday, or a week ago? I tried things such as

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT") and date=20120913
```

But it doesn't appear to work.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 13):

You're using the wrong table.

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "YHOO" and startDate = "2009-09-11" and endDate = "2010-03-10"
```

Alternatively, you could use [`stockretriever.py`](http://www.gurchet-rai.net/dev/yahoo-finance-yql) for this. In the [source code](https://github.com/gurch101/StockScraper/blob/master/stockretriever.py), you can find a workaround for historical data.

Comment: Do you know where you can find an ER diagram or a list of yahoo.finance tables u can use?

Comment: As far as I can tell this is not blocked at all.

Comment: It is working. You just need to include store parameter in query. append &diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys with your query string.

Answer (score 9):

The table is correct. You need to append the store parameter in your query string. Here is the sample string.

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "YHOO" and startDate = "2014-02-11" and endDate = "2014-02-18"&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 4):

yahoo.finance.historicaldata is working, but you have to use startDate and endDate:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT") and startDate = "2012-09-13" and endDate = "2012-09-13"
```

Comment: Although the table historicaldata does not appear in the console window one can still find that this is a service which YQL still supports. Yahoo has observed that this particular table causes spikes in server load and has tried to discourage individuals from using it.