# How to retrieve more than a month of stock quotes using Yahoo finance api?

Tags: json, node.js, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

Basically I'm new to using Yahoo finance Api. I've tried YQL Console but I can seem to find what I needed. I have to get like 3 months worth of stock quoute data. I found this http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/GOOG/chartdata;type=quote;range=30d/json

This is exactly the sets of data that I needed but it only gives me a whole month of data. No matter how I change the `range=30d` to say `range=90d` it gives me the same result.

Comment: See answer by Shahid Iqbal here: [How to Access Yahoo Finance YQL query with historical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417624/how-to-access-yahoo-finance-yql-query-with-historical-data) and change range to 3-months.

Comment: Not exactly the result I want. You see from my example it has all the ticks/series for each day. Basically what happened from start to end of the day. This one only gives one object for each day.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry cant comment due to my low reputation.

what you need to do exactly is use the following arguments in the url

30days: 30d
90days/ 3months: 3m
180days/ 6 months: 6m
365days/1 year: 1y

so the link for 3 months will be

http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/GOOG/chartdata;type=quote;range=3m/json

Hope it helps. :)