# YQL Console - No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quotes

Tags: xml, yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am currently learning how to query data via YQL, and wondering whether the tables : *yahoo.finance.quotes* && *yahoo.finance.historicaldata* nowadays work.

As a matter of fact, simple queries raised in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417624/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417624/how-to-access-yahoo-finance-yql-query-with-historical-data):

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT") 

select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT") and startDate = "2012-09-13" and endDate = "2012-09-13"
```

return:

```
<description>No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quotes</description>
```

However, I can see those tables available in **DATATABLES --> Show Community Tables**

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need to do, it to import **community table**. You can do something like this

```
env 'store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys'; select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")
```

In the [yql console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/), those tables only appear when you check **Show Community Table**

Hope it will help

Comment: I've seen the **Show Community Table** box (see post), but I acknowledge to have omitted from the YQL Console the following syntax `env 'store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys'`. Thanks, I do appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome buddy. If you're working with python, don't hesitate to check [mYQL](https://github.com/josuebrunel/myql) out. Have a good one

Comment: Look at your YQL Console URL. If you checked Show Community Tables, it should contain `&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys`. If it does, you don't need to type the `env` statement in your query. If not, add it, so you don't have to.