# Yahoo YQL finance to get historical Earning per share, market cap and BV per share

Tags: web-services, yahoo, yql, finance, yahoo-finance

I have had a read at Getting data from Yahoo Finance. I know what we can use YQL like 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("YHOO")'  However, I can only find the most recent earning per share and market captialisation of the company (not the historical one).

I also tried this linke [How to Access Yahoo Finance YQL query with historical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417624/how-to-access-yahoo-finance-yql-query-with-historical-data), select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT") and startDate = "2001-01-01" and endDate = "2015-01-01" in https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/. The historical data of the company only caters the price as far as I can found(not the earning per share or market capitalization, or shares outstanding)

i have tried to browse all the available finance table but can't find those data. Perhaps I miss something?

Is it possible for me to get the historical Market capitalisation, earning per share and If possible the book value per share as well? May I know the YQL for that? Thanks

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find something about this?

Comment: I believe Yahoo only returns the current information from key statistics.